# p5.js parent() | Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I do exactly as the library docs [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/parent).

I have an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" />
        <script src="libs/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/barcode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tried defer on the barcode script import, and putting it in the end.

barcode.js

```
function setup() {
    let cnv = createCanvas(500, 500);
    cnv.parent("container");
}
```

Tried this, nothing changed

```
async function setup() {
        let cnv = await createCanvas(500, 500);
        cnv.parent("container");
}
```

Thanks for your insight !

Comment: Add those script in the head to bottom. This is because javascript executed first and your page rendered later. That is why it do not detects `container`

Comment: what if add an id to container div and pass it to parent instead of classname?

Comment: @HDM91 How did I not think of this thank you so much ! Closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the p5 documentation says:

> The parent() function is used to attach the element as a parent
> element.
>
> This function accepts either a string ID, DOM node, or p5.Element Add

So add an id to container div and pass it to parent instead of class fix the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" />
        <script src="libs/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/barcode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```